# Should I use is or are after the word family

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, word-difference

Should I use is or are in this sentence? I don't know what the difference is. As I was trying to figure it out, plural and singular came to mind. Is family plural or singular and is that a factor?

1. Family is very important to me.
2. Family are very important to.

Comment: You'll see numerous similar questions/answers if you type *is are* in the *Search Q&A* box

Comment: *Family* is a countable noun and the singular form (the plural is *families*) so that's one reason to say *is*.  Can you think of a particular reason to say *are*?

Comment: This is one of the clearer differences between BrE and AmE. BrE tends to treat collective nouns like plurals and thus use *are*, and AmE treats them as singular, hence *is*.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on what you are trying to say.
In your first example

> Family **is** important to me.

would be understood to mean a family unit/structure has importance.

If you said

> The family **is** going on holiday.

it would be understood to mean they are all going together to the same place, whereas

> The family **are** going on holiday.

may be understood to mean the same or to mean the family is holidaying at the same time, but possibly in different places (not together), further context would be necessary to resolve the ambiguity.

However, your sentence

> Family **are** important to me.

would not exactly be incorrect but would be understood to mean that each individual in the family are important.